# How Exactly Is NONEMPTY Working Here?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I have a cube with two measure groups, one in MOLAP format and the other in ROLAP format.  I've also created a calculated member (`[C]`) from a single column in each of the member groups (`[A]` **MOLAP** and `[B]` **ROLAP**).  All I want is for `[C]` to return me the value of `[A]` if it is not empty, otherwise return `[B]`.  This is achieved pretty easily with a `CASE` statement:

```
WITH MEMBER [C] AS
    CASE
        WHEN ISEMPTY([A]) THEN [B]
        ELSE [A]
    END
```

This works great, and running the following query displays the results exactly like I would expect them to be displayed, where `[C]` is `[B]` only when `[A]` is empty.

```
SELECT
    { [A]
    , [B]
    , [C]
    } ON COLUMNS
    , [Time].CHILDREN ON ROWS
FROM    
    [Cube]
```

However,  there are some cases where both `[A]` and `[B]` are empty, and I would like to filter them out of the result set.  Normally, I would be able to just wrap the `[Time]` dimension in `NONEMPTY` to achieve this:

```
SELECT
    { [A]
    , [B]
    , [C]
    } ON COLUMNS
    , NONEMPTY([Time].CHILDREN) ON ROWS
FROM    
    [Cube]
```

But when I try this with the above query, the results filter out all of the rows where `[A]` is empty, regardless of whether or not `[B]` is empty.  Rows where `[B]` is empty are not filtered out.

I would expect that NONEMPTY would either:

1. Filter out only rows where `[C]` is empty (`[A]` and `[B]` are empty) **OR**
2. Filter out all rows where `[A]` OR `[B]` is empty

Why is `NONEMPTY` only taking `[A]` in to account here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `NonEmpty` function and the `NON EMPTY` key word. They do not have the same behavior.

If you write:

```
NON EMPTY [Time].CHILDREN ON ROWS
```

It will remove the empty rows.

The `NonEmpty` function does not take into account the other axes. Let's call `h1` the hierarchy of [A], [B] and [C]. In your case the `NonEmtpy` is computed on the default member of `h1`.

For your query

```
NONEMPTY([Time].CHILDREN) ON ROWS
```

is equivalent to

```
NONEMPTY([Time].CHILDREN, {[h1].DefaultMember}) ON ROWS
```

The following query should help you to understand what happens:

```
SELECT
    { [A]
    , [B]
    , [C]
    , [A].Hierarchy.DefaultMember
    } ON COLUMNS
    , [Time].CHILDREN ON ROWS
FROM    
    [Cube]
```

Comment: You are right, and `NON EMPTY` does what I want.  But in this case aren't `[A]` and `[B]` on the same axis?  Why would `NONEMPTY` only filter out the rows where `[A]` is empty, and not the ones where `[B]` is?

Comment: Ah, I see now. NONEMPTY is a special form of the FILTER function. It removes items from the first set that are empty across the second set. If you don't provide the second set, it just uses the default measure for your cube - in this case, [A]. If you want to test NONEMPTY against [C], you have to put [C] in the second parameter of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder about Measure [B]. Is it calculated? Apparently the default behavior of SSAS is to ignore calculated measures in set functions. NONEMPTY is a set function.What happens when you wrap the Time dimension in the AddCalculatedMembers function?

```
SELECT
    { [A]
    , [B]
    , [C]
    } ON COLUMNS
    , NONEMPTY(AddCalculatedmeasures([Time].CHILDREN)) ON ROWS
FROM    
    [Cube]
```

I also wonder if it worked better if you explicitly told the NONEMPTY function which measures to filter over. Perhaps your ROLAP measure group has other measures that are not empty over time even when [B] is. Remember the difference between NONEMPTY and NON EMPTY.

```
SELECT
    { [A]
    , [B]
    , [C]
    } ON COLUMNS
    , NONEMPTY([Time].CHILDREN, [C]) ON ROWS
FROM    
    [Cube]
```

Comment: `[B]` is not calculated, unless the fact that its ROLAP means that somehow it's treated as calculated since it's being processed on the fly.  There aren't any situations where one measure of a measure group is empty, but another wouldn't.  In this particular case, if a measure is empty it is because the entire row doesn't exist in the fact table.  I was able to achieve the functionality I was looking for both by using `NON EMPTY` as well as including `[C]` in `NONEMPTY` like your second example.  I didn't even know those options existed (new to MDX).

Comment: I'm able to achieve exactly what I wanted now, but I'm still not sure the reason NONEMPTY was only taking `[A]` into account.